# Is it possible to get "in-progress" responses from async/await, then use that to show what the server is currently doing before the await completes?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a simple axios call wrapped in a async/await below:

I want to show the progress of the call. In order for me to tap into that, what do i need to do with the await?

```js
let token = await axioslibs.getLogin(newparams);
```

Comment: What do you mean "progress of the call"? What do you want to show, to whom? Why? Please elaborate.

Comment: i think if you want all that (progress, errors, etc) you have to use promises instead of just _then_ / _await_.

Comment: @YannickK when user clicks a button, an axios call is made to an api. Lets assume api simply returns "hello world". But this is happening asynchronously so is there way for me to tap into the await (which wraps the axios) and show a "progress" of the call until value is returned?

Comment: there shouldn't be any progress on a quick call like that, only for large transfers.

Comment: @dandavis assuming it is a large transfer, lets say i am getting a token back, which would take a few seconds. Can I show a progress for await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For ajaxStart :**

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxStart handler." );
});
```

**For ajaxStop :**

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxStop handler." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the necessity of using await if you are already using the  progress bar to make your user wait until the response are coming...

Try to use "promise" feature of java-script and hide your progress bar once the data came back to javascript...

Comment: sorry i think i was explaining wrong. let me know if this makes sense...I don't currently have a progress bar at all. I have this await wrapped around an axios call which basically returns a token. Then return value takes a few seconds. I am wondering if there is a way to tap into any "in progress" responses and use that to build output to user until it completes? as an example: user clicks button --> then responses come out like this --> "calling api"-->waiting->token received-> then finally -> success! token is {token}

Comment: Ohkay.... Lets do one thing there is two event of javaScript where you can use them to show and hide the progressBar through out the application.  If there is any ajax call this two event will automatically call.. 

To accomplish this please follow the below point.

Comment: Ohkay.... Lets do one thing there is two event of javaScript where you can use them to show and hide the progressBar through out the application.  If there is any ajax call this two event will automatically call.. 

To accomplish this please follow the below point.

1. make a common file like common.js file 
2. Import it to main index.html page. 
3. In this javascript file add two methods (ajaxStart & ajaxStop) inside the document.ready function.

Do little bit R&D regarding these two event... if youm still have any query please do let me know...